# Why number of commits in GitHub UI are rounded off?

Tags: git, github

I have two GIt repos :

Original Repo : Repo A
Repo cloned from Repo A : Repo B

Locally, I ran filter-branch on Repo B and forced push it to a brand new Repo B on GitHub.

Now, for Repo B, master and develop branches are showing commit count as 10,000+, while for all other branches it shows the exact commit count : 42,000(more or less).

I cloned this repo locally, ran "git rev-list --count master" and got the commit number to be 42980.

Are there any known scenarios where GitHub interface will show rounded off numbers such as 10,000+ instead of exact number of commits, say 42980? How can I make GitHub show the exact count as I am seeing in a local clone. 
I need to verify if the filter-branch didn't mess up any commits.

(The original repo Repo A too shows exact count.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks us to speculate about why a particular feature works the way it does in a proprietary application.

Comment: Hey Chris, Thanks for your note. I'll change the language. I not only need to understand what's going on but to also find a fix for it.

Answer (score 0):

Sent a support query to GitHub. They replied and said it was a cache problem at their end. They cleared up the cache and the numbers came up fine.